# Why does Python Array Module Process Strings and Lists Differently?

Tags: python, arrays, type-conversion, python-module

I'm having trouble understanding the result of the following statements:

```
>>> from array import array
>>> array('L',[0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff])
array('L', [255L, 255L, 255L, 255L])


>>> from array import array
>>> array('L','\xff\xff\xff\xff')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: string length not a multiple of item size
```

Comment: Not putting this as an answer because I'm not actually sure about it, but my guess would be due to how one is stored versus the other - strings are most likely stored as actual blocks of memory, whereas lists are stored in a linked data structure (since the elements of a list can be all sorts of types, whereas strings are always a set of characters/bytes).

Comment: however it works with unsigned char and unsigned shorts, just not ints ???

Comment: @Dav: Python lists are NOT stored in a "linked data structure".

Comment: @John: Perhaps I phrased myself poorly - I wasn't meaning to imply a linked list or such, but rather a form of storage that involves storing references as opposed to storing each data value directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running this on a 64-bit build of Python, on which `array` treats type code `'L'` as a 64-bit unsigned integer.

```
>>> array('L','\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
array('L', [18446744073709551615L])
```

The documentation isn't very clear. All it says is that `'L'` is at least four bytes.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the issue ... I changed to 'I' and it work. A cursory glance of the document does not make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are initializing the array from a list with 4 elements. That will give you an array with 4 elements: one for each value in the list.

In the second case you are initializing the array from a byte string: the bytes in the string will be copied directly into the array. The 'L' specifier creates an array of unsigned longs which have a *minimum* size of 4 bytes.

On my machine (Windows 64 bit Python 2.6) initializing from a 4 byte string works fine:

```
>>> a = array('L','\xff\xff\xff\xff')

>>> a.tostring()
'\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```

I guess whichever version of Python you are using has unsigned longs that are 8 bytes rather than 4. Try converting the array you created from a list back to a string and see how many bytes that contains:

```
>>> a = array('L',[0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff])
>>> a.tostring()
'\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00'
```

P.S. I'm assuming that you are using Python 2.x, on Python 3.x you would have got a TypeError instead.